# Cocoapods duplicate Frameworks runtime errors

Tags: ios, frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods

I've been getting this error when running my app:

```
Class AClass is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/67C00CD1-BC3D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework 
and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/67C00CD1-BC3D/MyApp.app/MyApp 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I have a parent app that uses a framework with various dependencies.

I define the framework in my parent app podfile which then pulls in all the dependencies for that framework into the parent app and somehow is referencing them twice when I run the parent app?

Any ideas? 
Thanks,
Jennie

Comment: In addition I think this exception is also related to having duplicate FBAudienceNetwork frameworks: 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdTimer is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdTimer'

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No not yet. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Yes and no depends how you look at it... i have created a new project from scratch and done a new podinstall, after that everything was working. I could not find from where  it was called the second time, so i started from scratch... Sorry i cannot be of any help. I have not worked much with ios(btw mine was a react native project) so i do not have much understanding how the ios platform is functioning